# No default engine when registering user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Im getting this error when I try to register a new user in my MEAN app. Im not using a view engine. 
I've specified a static path (Node server.js):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
```

I've also specified a route to handle all angular requests

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});
```

The error occurs in this function (Angular authService.js):

```
function register(email, password) {

    // create a new instance of deferred
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // send a post request to the server
    $http.post('/user/register',
        {email: email, password: password})
    // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
            if (status === 200 && data.status) {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
            deferred.reject();
        });

    // return promise object
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

(Node routes.js):

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ email: req.body.email }),
        req.body.password, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    err: err
                });
            }
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: 'Registration successful!'
                });
            });
        });
});
```

I've done some logging and the post function in angular never reaches my routes.js 
I've tried other post/get/put calls using Postman, and I get the same error.

Comment: your post is to `user/register` but your route in node is `/register`.  it doesn't seem like your node function is ever being reached.

Comment: @Claies I've fixed that now, but it still dont works. I've done some logging and the post function in angular never reaches my routes.js